# Fast Update of thousands of rows in SQL database

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update one column value for all 19k rows I would like to know the fastest way of updating thousands of rows in a SQL database. Please suggest.

Below is the code I tried, but it's taking full day to execute which making the existing application freeze.

```
update table_name 
set column_name_value = 2
```

Comment: drop index if there is any then perform the update statement. once done, create the index again.

Comment: You should do some basic research before asking a question here, especially such an open-ended question.  Showing one line of code is hardly considered a well-made effort.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: thanks for your reply . I do not have any permission to drop the index . 
@marc_s yesterday -its for SQL server

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply changing the whole column to a single value, I would ask what is the point of having the column in the first place. Either way, If you're updating a LIVE production transactional database, I'd take a backup first.

If you are allowed, switch the database into SIMPLE mode. This will reduce the amount of space the trans log uses, or try BULK INSERT mode. This may not be an option.

That said, you can drop the column, and readd it with a default.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 2;
```

You may also do something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name WITH (TABLOCKX) SET column_name = 2;
```

If you cannot do any of the preceding, taking the database out of commission, then you may have to chunk your updates.

Try the following (if you happen to have a identity key on the table):

```
DECLARE @num_chunks INT = 10 -- this will break your update into 10 smaller updates
DECLARE @counter INT = 0

WHILE @counter < @num_chunks
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 2 
  WHERE (int_identity_column - @counter) % @num_chunks = 0

  PRINT 'DONE WITH GROUP ' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR) + ' AT ' + CAST(getdate() as varchar)

  SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Using this method will allow you to restart the process from where it left off, if you happen to have an issue and it gets interrupted.

Comment: If you would not mind upvoting my answer, I would greatly appreciate it!